# Prove that $\vDash_\Sigma\varphi\equiv\psi$ when $\psi$ is the disjunctive normal form of $\varphi$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I want to prove that $\varphi\equiv\psi$ is valid when $\psi$ is the disjunctive normal form of $\varphi$, where we can assume that $\varphi$ is quantifier-free (so its disjunctive normal form always exists).

My attempt goes as follows:

Let $\Sigma$ be a signature, and first assume that $\not\vDash_\Sigma \varphi\equiv\psi$, i.e. the formula is not valid. This means that there exists an interpretation structure $I$ such that $I \not\Vdash_\Sigma \varphi\equiv\psi$, and so, for some assignment $\rho$ over $I$, it holds that $I\rho \not\Vdash_\Sigma \varphi\equiv\psi$.

Now, suppose that $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi$. Since $\psi$ is the disjunctive normal form of $\varphi$, any assignment $\rho$ over $I$ that contextually satisfies $\varphi$ must also contextually satisfy $\psi$, i.e. $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \psi$, and vice-versa. But then $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi\equiv\psi$, which is a contradiction.

I feel like there may be some (if not many) flaws with this argument, and that it could be simplified (if it is correct).

Comment: It sounds circular reasoning from your above "suppose that $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi$. Since $\psi$ is the disjunctive normal form of $\varphi$, any assignment $\rho$ over $I$ that contextually satisfies $\varphi$ must also contextually satisfy $\psi$". You didn't really use any features of DNF in your proof. As refed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form): *Every particular Boolean function can be represented by one and only one full disjunctive normal form*, you can directly use this feature (how to prove?) for your $\rho$ with its inductive definition up to primes.

Comment: My idea was that $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi\equiv\psi$ whenever $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi$ iff $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \psi$ by definition. The property of DNF I'm intending to use here is the fact that $\varphi$ is true (false) iff its DNF $\psi$ is true (false), respectively, i.e. the DNF operator preserves contextual satisfaction. So $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \varphi$ iff $I\rho \Vdash_\Sigma \psi$.

Comment: Ok. Regarding your "The property of DNF I'm intending to use here is the fact that φ is true (false) iff its DNF ψ is true (false)", if you have this fact (feature) avail, then your goal can be immediate from the definition of logical $\equiv$ (truth value equal under any assignment $\rho$) and without any need of non-constructive proof by contradiction. But we cannot say it's because DNF operator preserves contextual satisfaction since DNF is not an operator/function. As hinted in my first comment, it's not obvious why any formula can be converted to a unique canonical DNF from its definition